# JavaScript readstream line by line

Tags: javascript, file, csv, io

I'm trying to read in a CSV file line by line and add each line to an array, my code so far is:

```
var csvFile = 'Domain.csv';
var fs = require('fs');
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream(csvFile);
var data = '';

readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    var temp = '';
    temp = chunk;
    global.qArray.push(temp);
});

readableStream.on('end', function() {
    console.log(global.qArray);
});
```

This logs:

> `[ <Buffer 22 54 79 70 65 20 28 53 74 72 69 6e 67 29 22 2c 22 44 6f 6d 61 69 6e 20 28 53 74 72 69 6e 67 29 22 2c 22 41 76 65 72 61 67 65 49 6d 70 72 65 73 73 69 ... > ]`

to the console. I'm assuming this means my readstream isn't taking in chunks line by line. Can anyone tell me how I can change it so it reads each line individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easier if you go easier ...

```
var fs = require('fs'),
readline = require('readline');

 var rd = readline.createInterface({
 input: fs.createReadStream('Domain.csv'),
 output: process.stdout,
 terminal: false
});

rd.on('line', function(line) {
  console.log(line);
});
```

Comment: do you know how I can do something like rd.on('end', function() ....}); here? because that's not working with your code. @shane_yo

Comment: `rd.on("close", ..);` can be used as a callback (occurrs when all lines are read) –  steebchen Feb 16

Comment: *readline* / *linebyline* limits the maximum line length to 4K (default, can be adjusted). Limiting the length of messages is just stupid and results in unexpected broken data. Wouldn't use *linebyline*.